# object detection with the yolov4 model in Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using the Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

I try to run the yolov4 model in Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using the Tensorflow Lite.
I took the codes and tried to follow the instructions from the following link and it ran successfully in my pc but not in raspberry.:
https://github.com/haroonshakeel/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite

Used these commands in rasbian:

```
cd Projects/tflite/
python -m pip install virtualenv
python -m venv tflite-env
source tflite-env/bin/activate
sudo apt -y install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
sudo apt -y install qt4-dev-tools libatlas-base-dev libhdf5-103
python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
uname -a
uname -m
python --version
python -m pip install https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

And for the run:

```
python save_model.py --weights ./data/yolov4.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-416 --input_size 416 --model yolov4 --framework tflite
```

And it gave me:

```
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info
```

I ran the following command for the weights:

```
python convert_tflite.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-416 --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-416-fp16.tflite --quantize_mode float16
```

And had this error:

```
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = ' ./checkpoints/yolov4-416', erno = 21, error message = 'Is a directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)
```

Finally, when i tried to run the detection with this command:

```
python detect_video.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-416.tflite --size 416 --model yolov4 --video ./data/videoNIR.AVI
```

I had this error:

```
TypeError(): load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'export dir'
```

Any way how to solve these errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The commands for building the tflite model should not be executed on the raspberry. You do everything on your PC and after on the raspberry you must execute the detection command.Note also that if you have not connected a screen on your raspberry, the code will not be able to work because it is still looking for used the GUI could be executed, which it will not find !!